# How to support both HTML4 and HTML5?

Tags: html, css

So I have a complete website written in HTML4 with CSS2/CSS3 support - i.e. mainly taking advantages of most of the CSS3 where supported.

I want to upgrade the site to support HTML5 - but little confused [using Visual Studio 2010 / ASP.NET MVC etc] how I can support both HTML4 and HTML5 ?

Do I need to rewrite the entire site in HTML5 or ? Little confused how to support both HTML4 and HTML5 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

HTML5 is an umbrella term for a collection of loosely-related client-side features supported by recent browsers.
You can just use any features you like.

Just make sure to implement a fallback so that the site still works in browsers that don't support the new features.
The [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library can be very useful here.

---

You can use the new HTML5 *tags* even in HTML4.
However, you'll need to include a [shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) to make them style-able in IE < 9.
Modernizr already includes this.

Comment: sorry - so to clarify - are you suggesting you can incorporate <article> and <section> inside HTML4 valid pages ? won't this invalidate these pages in HTML4?

Comment: [after edit] - so does this mean I can rewrite HTML4 pages to include <article> and <section> and <aside> HTML5 and this will still operate in HTML4 ? is this recommended or ?

Comment: If you're using `<article>` and `<section>` you should be using `<!DOCTYPE html>`(HTML5 doctype) - so your pages will validate - unless I misunderstand.

Comment: @Tom: Yes and yes.  Just use a shiv for IE.

Comment: @SLaks - thanks a lot. Was confused how this worked :) So basically I can update all my HTML4 pages to HTML5 [a lot of work it seems] so use this new <article> and <section> elements etc with a shiv ?

Comment: You don't need to use new elements at all; they won't give you any concrete benefits.  If you already have working pages, there's no point in rewriting them.

Comment: ah sure ok :) - so basically just change to the new doctype ?

Answer (score 0):

What HTML5-specific elements do you need on your page?  Are you using things like audio, video, canvas, etc. elements?  If you're not, then a HTML4-compliant site should be HTML5-compliant as well.

By the way, you can now get [HTML5 Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 and 2008](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d).

Comment: yeah thanks - but i'm confused how to write pages with <article> and <section> and the like that will be HTML4 compatible ? i.e. they're not HTML4 attributes ?

Comment: added a better VS2010 plugin for HTML5/CSS3